# java.io.FileNotFoundException while running code from jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am facing file not found exception while trying to run my test from jenkins , on my local its working as expected, however when m running it from jenkins it should search the file in jenkins workspace instead of my local path
C:\Users\user.name\eclipse-workspace\projectFolder\src\test\java\resources\global.properties

can any one help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I don't know what your project structure looks like. All Jenkins jobs have their own workspace path. I guess you check out your project into the workspace by job configuration.

To search a file from the workspace path you can just use the global `WORKSPACE` variable like `env.WORKSPACE/my/test/resource/path/`.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables

Comment: thanks @magro, have also tried with similar way i.e. system.getProperty("user.dir')/my/test... , its working fine now.

Comment: If you have test resources, you should access them via classloader, not with simple path expressions.